# Connection from android client to servlet

Tags: java, android, servlets, connection, filenotfoundexception

Hello I have a strange problem with my application. I tried to connect a android client to a Servlet but I get a `FileNotFoundException` when I run my android application. I made a java web project in Netbeans with multiple controllers, when I connect to the first Servlet that I create everything works fine but when I try to connect to a different Servlet I get the exception.

I'm using these two URLs :

http://10.0.2.2:8080/HelloWordlServlet2/HelloWorld (this works fine, and it's the first servlet that i create)

http://10.0.2.2:8080/HelloWordlServlet2/GetList (this is not working, i get FileNotFoundException when i try the connection)

I am deploying the server before using the android app, I will post the `web.xml` below so maybe the issue is there.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd">
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>HelloWorld</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>Controller.HelloWorld</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>GetList</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>Controller.GetList</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>HelloWorld</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/HelloWorld</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>GetList</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/GetList</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>
        30
    </session-timeout>
</session-config>
</web-app>
```

here is the code for the activity

```
public class LoginPanel extends AppCompatActivity {
Button showListButton;
EditText showListText;
public String URL =
        "http://10.0.2.2:8080/HelloWordlServlet2/GetList";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login_panel);
    findId();
    setOnClickListenerButton();

}

public void findId(){
    showListButton= (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_show_list);
    showListText= (EditText)findViewById(R.id.text_show_list);

}

public void setOnClickListenerButton(){
    showListButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            getListConnection test = new getListConnection();
            test.execute(URL);
        }
    });

}

private class getListConnection extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        StringBuffer output = new StringBuffer("ciao");

        try {
            java.net.URL url = new URL(URL); //Enter URL here
            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
            httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("GET"); // here you are telling that it is a POST request, which can be changed into "PUT", "GET", "DELETE" etc.
            //httpURLConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json"); // here you are setting the `Content-Type` for the data you are sending which is `application/json`
            httpURLConnection.connect();
            //if (httpURLConnection.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                InputStream in = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
                BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(in));
                String s = "";
                while ((s = buffer.readLine()) != null)
                    output.append(s);
            //}
        }catch (MalformedURLException e){
            e.printStackTrace();

        }catch (IOException e){
            Log.d("errore","Non trovo il file");
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
        return output.toString();
    }
    protected void onPostExecute(String output) {
        showListText.setText(output);
    }
}
}
```

the server that i'm using is glassfish, anyone can help me? ty

this is the error log

```
05-15 14:12:19.754 20338-20367/com.example.luchino.simplehttpgetservlet D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
05-15 14:12:19.878 20338-20367/com.example.luchino.simplehttpgetservlet D/errore: Non trovo il file
05-15 14:12:19.878 20338-20367/com.example.luchino.simplehttpgetservlet W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://10.0.2.2:8080/HelloWordlServlet2/GetList
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:250)
    at com.example.luchino.simplehttpgetservlet.LoginPanel$getListConnection.doInBackground(LoginPanel.java:68)
    at com.example.luchino.simplehttpgetservlet.LoginPanel$getListConnection.doInBackground(LoginPanel.java:53)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:304)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:243)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
05-15 14:12:19.879 20338-20367/com.example.luchino.simplehttpgetservlet W/System.err:     at  java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
```

Comment: are you using android studio or eclipse ?

Comment: Can you paste all error from logcat?

Comment: i'm using android studio

Comment: You cannot get data from your server, try call `httpURLConnection.getResponseCode()` to check response code of your request. I think there is something wrong in your url, or something is blocking of your requests (firewall, antivirus)

Comment: ok i fix the problem, the connection is working the problem was when i try to setDoInput(true) and setDoOutput(true), i dunno why but now is working XD ty for the help